# Using Select 2 with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. In my app, I'm trying to replace my drop down lists with the [Select 2 plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). Currently, I'm having problems loading data from my ASP.NET MVC controller. My controller looks like this:

```
public class MyController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
  [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MyItem>))]
  public IHttpActionResult Get(string startsWith)
  {
    IEnumerable<MyItem> results = MyItem.LoadAll();
    List<MyItem> temp = results.ToList<MyItem>();

    var filtered = temp.Where(r => r.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(startsWith.ToLower());
    return Ok(filtered);
  }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in this code, I notice that `startsWith` does not have a value The fact that the breakpoint is being hit means (I think) my `url` property below is set correct. However, I'm not sure why `startsWith` is not set. I'm calling it from Select 2 using the following JavaScript:

```
function formatItem(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

function formatSelectedItem(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

$('#mySelect').select2({
  placeholder: 'Search for an item',
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/my',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    quietMillis: 150,
    data: function (term, page) {
      return {
        startsWith: term
      };
    },
    results: function (data, page) {
      return { results: data };
    }
  },
  formatResult: formatItem,
  formatSelection: formatSelectedItem
});
```

When this code runs, the only thing I see in the select 2 drop down list is `Loading failed`. However, I know my api is getting called. I can see in fiddler that a 200 is coming back. I can even see the JSON results, which look like this:

```
[
{"Id":1,"TypeId":2,"Name":"Test", "CreatedOn":"2013-07-20T15:10:31.67","CreatedBy":1},{"Id":2,"TypeId":2,"Name":"Another Item","CreatedOn":"2013-07-21T16:10:31.67","CreatedBy":1}
]
```

I do not understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Well, your code snippet is missing a closing `'` in `$('#mySelect)`. Is this corrected in your project?

Comment: yes it is. fixing the code snippet now.

Comment: I don't see a property in your json called `text`.  Unless you've overridden the behavior somehow in a funciton handler, both a `id` and `text` property is required for each item.

Comment: Also, don't know if these are case sensitive, I would try `Id` -> `id`.

Comment: @AaronLS Why is a property called `text` required in the json? Is that a select 2 thing? I don't see it mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @user70192 It's required because it needs display text for each item, and there's no way it can magically guess which of your properties you intended to use for display.  It is documented under the ajax and query documentation: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#doc-query

Comment: Why isn't the `startsWith` parameter in my controller populated though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

> Select2 provides some shortcuts that make it easy to access local data
>   stored in an array...
>
> ... such an array must have "id" and "text" keys.

Your json object does not contain "id" or "text" keys :) This *should* work though i have not tested it:

```
results: function (data, page) {
   return { results: data, id: 'Id', text: 'Name' }
}
```

There's further documentation following the link on alternative key binding... I believe thats where your problem lies.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hello, but why isn't the `startsWith` parameter in my controller populated?

Comment: I think its the same sort of issue... try replacing 'data : function(term, page){...}' with 'data : { startsWith : "Test" }'

Comment: This should hit your controller. The Select 2 ajax "shortcut" is just wrapping a normal ajax call.